# count i+1 or i-1 at Django view

Tags: python, django, view

I want to create an `up-vote` and a `down-vote` view from my `category_request` page, but how do I count the integer field. Should it be done by `i+1` or `i-1`?

```
def category_request_up_vote (request, pk):
    category_request = get_object_or_404(CategoryRequests, pk=pk)
    try:
        if request.method == 'GET':
            category_request.up_vote() << here i guess
            messages.success(request, 'You have successfully Provided an Up-Vote for this Request')
            return redirect('category_request_detail', pk=category_request.pk)
        else:
            messages.success(request, 'Uuups, something went wrong, please try again.')
            return redirect('category_request_detail', pk=category_request.pk)
    except Exception as e:
        messages.warning(request, 'Uuups, something went wrong, please try again. Error {}'.format(e))
```

models.py

```
...
up_vote = models.IntegerField(default=0)
down_vote = models.IntegerField(default=0)
...
```

I guess that I don't have to mention I'm new to Python/Django ^^

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just adding 1 to a value and saving the model instance can cause the **race condition** situation. If two users calls up_vote function at the exact same time you can loose some of their votes.

To avoid race conditions you should use [select_for_update](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.select_for_update) method (if your db supports such operation).

Or use [F()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions) expression. In this case database will increase actual value, not the value stored in memory few moments ago (which may be outdated)

```
from django.db.models import F

...
category_request.up_vote = F('up_vote') + 1
category_request.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

To add 1 to the `vote_up` attribute of your `category_request` model instance, you can manipulate the object's attributes directly :

```
category_request.up_vote += 1
category_request.save()
```

Is that what you're looking for ?

Comment: Seems fine :D
Any idea how i can accomplish that every user can only vote once ? either once up or once down but not both?

Comment: Firstly that would require to implement a way for users to log in. Each user could have an `has_voted` attribute, that you would set to True when the user votes. Before voting, you'd need to check that that user's hasn't voted before.

Comment: Do you maybe have an example for me how to implement?